# mutable object referred by std::any

Tags: c++, c++17, stdany

Is only the way to modify, not replace, an object stored  as `std::any` is to declare changeable data mutable? E.g. to avoid creation and copy of class S instances:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>
#include <string>
    
struct S {
    mutable std::string str;
    
    S(S&& arg) : str(std::move(arg.str)) { std::cout << ">> S moved" << std::endl; }
    S(const S& arg) : str(arg.str) { std::cout << ">> S copied" << std::endl; }
    S(const char *s) : str(s) { std::cout << ">> S created" << std::endl; }
    
    S& operator= (const S& arg) { str = arg.str; return *this; }
    S& operator= (S&& arg) { str = std::move(arg.str); return *this; }
    virtual ~S() { std::cout << "<< S destroyed" << std::endl; }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<std::any> container;

    container.emplace_back(S("Test 1"));
    
    std::any_cast<const S&>(container[0]).str = "Test 2";
    
    for (const auto& a : container) {
        std::cout << a.type().name() << ", " 
                  << std::any_cast<const S&>(a).str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't understand your problem. If I remove `mutable` and change any-cast to `any_cast<S&>`, it works: https://godbolt.org/z/ocrj4s. Does this solves your problem? Why do you any-cast to `<const S&>`?

Comment: @DanielLangr something what accidently fell out of code after simplification. a const cast hidden in template parameters, std::any received was `const std::any&`

Comment: "object referred by std::any" the value within a `std::any` isn't a reference, it's an object in its own right.

Comment: @Caleth it's not located within `std::any` storage, `std::any`  is functionally safer version of  `void*`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `container.emplace_back(S("Test 1"));` allocates some dynamic storage and constructs an `S`, copied from the temporary, owned by the `std::any` it is also constructing.

Comment: To avoid the copy in the `emplace_back`, you can `container.emplace_back(std::in_place_type<S>, "Test 1");`

Comment: @Caleth Oh, good catch, wish I could give more credit for that. New components are.. a little new to me still after being stuck for years in C++98-locked industry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can any_cast with non-const reference:

```
std::any_cast<S&>(container[0]).str = "Test 2";
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99042e24e857589a)

or

```
std::any a = 40;

std::any_cast<int&>(a) += 2;
std::cout << std::any_cast<int>(a) <<std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afbb7dee4585113b)

Answer (score 0):

nope.

The issue is here.

```
std::any_cast<const S&>(container[0]).str = "Test 2";
```

you are trying to change constant data

Comment: I know that, it just feels strange that `std::any` appears to be the only container with unmutable content in component library, even reference wrapper isn't, it creates impression that something is missing.